# Is there another example where the same word is pronounced differently other than Zeal and Overzealous?

Tags: pronunciation

This has been bugging me for almost a month now.

The reason why I am considering them the same word is because overzealous doesn't change the meaning of zeal in it, while Zealot does.

Is there a term for this example?

Comment: I don't understand why you say "overzealous" *doesn't* change the meaning of "zeal", but "zealot" *does*. What about, for example, the noun "permit" = a piece of paper (a *license*) as opposed to the verb "to permit" = to *allow* someone to do something? Does *that* "change the meaning"?

Comment: A zealot is a person who shows extreme zeal, surely?

Comment: The duplicate ID here doesn’t really work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what your question means. There is no reasonable linguistic sense in which *zealous* (never mind *overzealous*) contains the "word" *zeal*. It just happens that our imperfect writing system uses the same sequence of letters to denote different sounds in this pair of related words.
This happens often. *Mouth* (noun) and *mouth* (verb) sound different, but are spelt the same. Ditto *live* (verb) and *live* (adjective). Compare also pairs like *insane* and *insanity* - the letters of one word are not precisely contained in the second word, but the same thing is going on.

Comment: Overzealous does not contain the word zeal?  Is the problem here defining a word?  Are not over and ous a prefix and suffix preceding and following a . . . word?

Comment: What prefixes and suffixes are added to is usually a "stem" or "root". Occasionally this might happen to correspond exactly to a word, but most often it does not.